# What was the origin of the idea that Centaur race hold some divining/astrological ability?

Tags: harry-potter, centaurs

Was the idea that Centaurs as a race have some special divination/prediction abilities a JKR invention, or did the idea appear elsewhere before (books, or original myths?).

I am specifically referring to centaurs being USERS of the arts, not centaurs being [astrological objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurs_in_astrology) or constellations.

Please note that i'm referring to Centaurs as a race - it's known that [Chiron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiron) was an astrologer in Greek Mythos, but he was also NOT actually related to other Centaurs nor had much in common with them, seemingly.

Comment: Although you've "nipped it", the idea that Chiron was a master astrologer propagates an idea linking centaurs to astrology.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - that's what Wikia says, and that was my impression from reading the books.

Comment: if there is evidence in Greek myths that non-Chiron centaurs were also astrologers, that'd constitute a very acceptable answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this origin question excludes the obvious catalyst "**Chiron**", I'm going to throw in a token example: **CS Lewis' Narnia** series has Centaurs skilled in astrology.

[Narnian Centaurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narnian_Centaurs)

They can do astrology and are skilled in healing.
From that same article, see the quote:

> In Greek tales, centaurs were nearly always a wild race who were violent, womanizing, and usually intoxicated. The centaurs of Narnia are based on a unique and well known Greek centaur, **Chiron**, who, unlike all the other centaurs, was a noble, wise, and powerful being.

I believe there is an understanding that if there are noble/wise centaurs, they are based on Chiron as he is a *very* popular early centaur. All others in Greek mythology represent man's base desires. Drunkenness, lust, battle, feasting, unbridled passion and chaos were the ream of non-Chiron centaurs.

So, while you're explicitly cutting Chiron out, any pre-Narnia examples of astrologically skilled centaurs are most certainly *also* based on Chiron.

Chiron is also known as: "**Centaurus**" who was said to have done the original pairings of stars to make the constellations:

> Centaurus was the first person to group stars into constellations and taught others how to read them. One explanation of the constellation is that Centaurus put a picture of himself in the sky to guide his sailor friends the Argonauts.

Chiron and Centaurus may or may not have been always the same person, but they typically are.

Comment: Well, if a specific work/universe has ALL of their Centaur race based on Chiron, that counts as an answer to my question. My problem with Chiron himself was that he was widely NON-representative of his race in his universe.

Comment: Narnia isn't a complete throw-away, I would consider it highly influential. Between Narnia and LOTR the mold was set for modern works of fantasy.